# How can I clean up this Objective C cornerRadius code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am doing the same thing multiple times to different buttons. This is my current code, how can I clean it up to apply this same styling in one go?

Thank you!

```
appExclusivesButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
appExclusivesButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

emailDealButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
emailDealButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

dotwButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
dotwButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

exclusiveButtonl.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
exclusiveButtonl.clipsToBounds = YES;

clearanceButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
clearanceButton.clipsToBounds = YES;


harlowButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
harlowButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
walthamstowButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
walthamstowButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
leytonButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
leytonButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
loughtonButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
loughtonButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: `-(void)applyCornerRadius:(CGFloat)value onView:(UIView *)view { view.layer.cornerRadius = 10; view.clipsToBound = YES; }` and `NSArray *views = @[appExclusiveButton, emailDealButton, etc.]; for (UIView *aView in views) { [self applyCornerRadius:10 onView:aView]; }`, or something like that? `applyCornerRadius:onView:` could be a `UIView` extension, etc.

Comment: You must need to do it multiple times. If you think code is heavy. Then do this in story board. Set corner radius at run time attributes.  You can create custom extension button class. But right now as per your requirement no need it.

Comment: You could also consider making a custom class for your button, or a category that returns a new configured button.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to apply `cornerRadius` and `clipsToBounds` to all buttons is to make an array, in which you put all your buttons. Then loop through the buttons in your array and apply values for the desired properties.

Example use:

```
for (UIButton *button in buttonArray) {
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    button.clipsToBounds = YES:
}
```

You can combine this approach with the answer of [Sanjukta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53758888/9988514) and write a method that sets `cornerRadius` and `clipsToBounds` (or any other property) for your buttons.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a `UIButton` category that allows you to set the corner radius.
You could either create a factory method that returns a new button with rounded corners, or one that applies rounded corners to an existing button.

Here's an example that does both:

```
//  UIButton+RoundedCorners.h
@interface UIButton (RoundedCorners)

+(instancetype)buttonWithRoundedCorners;
-(void)addRoundedCorners;

@end


//  UIButton+RoundedCorners.m
@implementation UIButton (RoundedCorners)

+(instancetype)buttonWithRoundedCorners {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    button.clipsToBounds = YES;
    return button;
}


-(void)addRoundedCorners {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

@end
```

Then if you import the category you can use it like this:

```
 UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithRoundedCorners];
```

or

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton addRoundedCorners];
```

Comment: If you're going to add a category to a system class (generally not a great pattern to start with), at least prefix your methods with something, as recommended.

Comment: @bbum good point about the naming, I meant this as just an example of how it could be done, didn’t think too hard about method names. But why shouldn’t you add a category to a system class?

Comment: It creates layering issues that are a maintenance nightmare over time.   Effectively, you're creating a layer on top of each framework that you add a category too.

Comment: I think calling categories a maintenance nightmare is a bit over the top, I've literally never had a problem like that on any size project. Even naming clashes are pretty unlikely, although I agree it's best practice to use prefixes.

Comment: The naming clashes are over the top until you have one.  Like, for example, -addObjectIfAbsent:.   That was a fiasco and a half that made dozens of WebObjects based sites corrupt data at the most surprising time.  And the layering issue is very real;  can't tell you how many hours of the 30+ years I've spent programming ObjC that has had to detangle layering issues.  Make refactoring a giant pain in the ass.   There is a reason why we devoted a part of a session at WWDC a decade ago to discourage people from using categories.

Answer (score 1):

By using category class of uibutton. Just make a category class of uibutton add your method to add the radius and all want to add on button. And just import that class in your class and call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass UIButton, put your style code there
i.e.

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

And then instantiate your own UIButton class.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer by Rainer (i do this too sometimes). But looping thru controls can be messy especially when the buttons are places in multiple views. I guess the refactor way is to create a method to do 2 things at once and supplying the button to the method, like so:

```
-(void)stylizeButton:(UIButton*)btn {
  btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
  btn.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Then,

```
[self stylizeButton:appExclusivesButton];
[self stylizeButton:emailDealButton];
[self stylizeButton:dotwButton];
[self stylizeButton:exclusiveButtonl];
[self stylizeButton:clearanceButton];
[self stylizeButton:harlowButton];
[self stylizeButton:walthamstowButton];
[self stylizeButton:leytonButton];
[self stylizeButton:loughtonButton];
```

Still a bit repetitive but more organized.

Alternatively you can consider making your own custom button where you can
add and stylize in Storyboard. Tutorial here: https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-custom-ui-components-live-rendering-xcode/